# SQL Azure V12 BACPAC import error: "The internal target platform type SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider does not support schema file version '3.5'."

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms-2014, bacpac

Today, Jan. 20, 2017, I created a BACPAC file from a SQL Azure V12 database, and when I went to import it to a local SQL Server 2014 instance using SQL Server Management Studio 2014, I got this error:

> The internal target platform type SqlAzureV12DatabaseSchemaProvider
>   does not support schema file version '3.5'. (File: [filepath])
>   (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Note that I found several similar questions to this here on StackOverflow, but none with the exact same error message or same solution.  I tried installing the [Microsoft® SQL Server® Data-Tier Application Framework (17.0 RC 1)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54273), but that didn't help. (If there's a newer version, I couldn't find it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After downloading and installing [SQL Server Management Studio 2016 (v16.5.1)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), I was able to use that to successfully import the BACPAC file.  Note that it's a 1GB download and takes 30 minutes or more to install.

Comment: I installed SQL Server Management Studion 17 to fix the issue.